# How to gather a number that has to be formatted like a String?

Tags: java, json, string

I'm developing a Jersey REST client that consumes JSON and takes a value that represents money, but that value has to be formatted into a String with 16 characters before the dot and two characters after the dot, this means that the String will be padded with zeroes to complete the needed length.

JSON String that will be sent to Web Service:

...
"Amout":"0000000000000001.00",
...

I have an object representing the request and an @JsonProperty annotated String field for amount, but I'm not sure how to gather the String before sending it.

Should I have a String setter that accepts any String and control the formatting of the String in another class?

Should I have a String setter that accepts and validates the value prior to formatting it?

Or should I have a numeric setter that converts the amount to String and passes it to the String field?

Comment: I like the answer given by Forseth11 (I upvoted his answer).  Alternatively, you can use a regular expression to verify that the given string pattern correspond to a numeric value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so you would have to:

- read any representation of the number:
      - "000[...]001.00" 
      - "0.09"
      - "2.43"
- always write it as "00[...]001.00"

if that's the case, i would probably go with a String setter that parses, validates and formats anything incoming. this gives you a reasonable balance of freedom vs control.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your string to a double by doing `Double.parseDouble(string);`
You will use a double because you are using a decimal point and I am assuming that the decimal is not always .00.